# UIActivityIndicator not stopping when UICollectionView is reloaded

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview

**Needed Result:**

I have a small issue coming up with UIActivityIndicator and UICollectionView. I start activity indicator when the request is send and stop as the response comes. When the response comes i reload collection view.

**Problem:**

But activity indicator does not stops even response has come. I tried to stop it forcefully but that does not work. I even tried to check if another request is send or not.

I am using AFNetworking to send request.
It takes lot of time to reload.

Comment: post some code... That will explain exactly wht's going

Comment: If you are using AFNetworking then you should use builtin methods for handling network indicator. Which version are you using for AFNetworking?

Answer (score 0):

In the `success` and `failure` blocks, just make it stop in the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_myActivity stopAnimating];
});
```

Comment: `_myActivity = nil; [_myActivity removeFromSuperview];` if you want it to take it to the next level? XD

Comment: hey! Apptality... thanks for the help but tried this solution as well... didn't worked for me!!!